# Changing characters of a word to asterisks

Tags: java, class, methods

This is supposed to change `randomWord` to all asterisks

```
WordHider secretWord = new WordHider();         
secretWord.setSecretWord(randomWord);
System.out.println(secretWord);
```

and the method from the other class that sets the `randomWord`

```
public void setSecretWord(String newSecretWord) {
    secretWord = newSecretWord.toLowerCase();
    if (secretWord.length() > 0) {
        wordMask = HIDE_CHAR;
        for (int i = 1; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
            wordMask += HIDE_CHAR;
        }
```

All im getting is `program3.WordHider@a37368` for the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that because that is the object's `WorldHider` default toString method. You need to override that if you want it to print something else.

Or create a method in that class that prints the secret word. Something like this to call it

```
System.out.println(secretWord.getSecretWord());
```

And the actual getter method could be

```
public String getSecretWord() {
return wordMask;
}
```

Comment: well that prints the `secretWord` again, but the `setSecretWord` method is supposed to change `secretWord` to all *'s

Comment: @tawnpawt Make sure you're calling the set method before you print it.

Comment: like this ? `secretWord.getSecretWord();` sorry if these are dumb questions haha im fairly new

Comment: It seems to me that the `toString()` method should, in this case, return `wordMask`, not `secretWord`.

Comment: @Simon I just saw that, and changed my getter method.

Comment: @tawnpawt You have to make sure you call `secretWord.setSecretWord(randomWord);` first, and check out the new `getSecretWord` method.

Comment: `secretWord.setSecretWord(randomWord);
        System.out.println(secretWord);
        secretWord.getSecretWord();
        System.out.println(secretWord.getSecretWord());` is what i have now, they both return the word but not in *

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is creating a new `WordHider` object, setting one of its attributes with the `setSecretWord` method, and then printing the *object* instead of the attribute. Your `WordHider` class probably has a `getSecretWord` or `printSecretWord` method that will do what you want.

If that method doesn't exist, you just need to print the `WordHider`'s `wordMask` attribute. Try replacing your print statement with:

```
    System.out.println(secretWord.wordMask);
```

If wordMask is a private attribute, you may need to write a new method for the `WordHider` class to return it.

Comment: i have a `getSecretWord` that just returns the secretWord. im definitely supposed to use `setSecretWord` in some way

Comment: its telling me wordMask has private access

Comment: You're using setSecretWord correctly. It sounds like you need to access wordMask through a method, though. If there isn't already one that returns it, you can write a public `getWordMask` method yourself (assuming you're allowed to write new methods).